# Get the last 5 days of last month using Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I just want to get the last 5 days of last month using carbon

I'm using this code to get the last day of last month

```
$lastDay = new Carbon('last day of last month')
```

I already search on the internet but I cannot find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already have an answer to this

```
$lastDay = new Carbon('last day of last month');
$lastMonthDays = [];
$lastDays = $lastDay->format('d') - 5;
$day = $lastDay->format('d');

for($i = $lastDays +1 ; $i <= $day; $i++){
  $lastMonthDays[] = $i;
}
```